# Protractor: TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

Currently having an issue trying to figure out why the following element is throwing the error "TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of undefined" when it is trying to be clicked.

```
browser.driver.sleep(2000);

// Undefined, figure out why it cant get a hold of this
expect(element.all(by.css('[ng-value="account.id"]')).get(0).isPresent()).toBe(true);

element.all(by.css('[ng-value="account.id"]')).get(0).then(function (elm) {
    browser.driver.sleep(1000);
    elm[0].click();
});
```

The elements being looked at are below (There are multiple which is why I am calling ".get(0)" to just look at the first radio button in the set of them):

```
<div class="row row-center" style="height: 85%;">
       <div class="col">
         <div class="list card" ng-if="accounts != null">
            <div class-="list">
                <label class="item item-radio"
                       ng-repeat="account in accounts" ng-if="account.clippable && account.fundable">
                    <input type="radio"
                           ng-model="accountConnection.id"
                           ng-value="account.id" >
                    <div class="item-content">
                        {{ account.meta.name }} ({{ account.meta.number }})
                        <p>${{ account.balance.current }}</p>

                    </div>
                    <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `elm[0].click()`? What happens if you use `elm.click()` instead? Can you verify that `elm` contains the control you're looking for?

Comment: If I use "elm.click()" instead I get the error:  ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible.

Comment: I have a expect(element.all(by.css('[ng-value="account.id"]')).get(0).isPresent()).toBe(true); right above where I try to call the click and it is not erroring out, so I figured that meant the element was visible.

Comment: Just to verify what's going on, can you add a `browser.sleep(1000);` before the click? That's obviously not a permanent solution, but it should give you a hint that the page is still not finished loading.

Comment: I updated the original comment with the sleeps that I have in place, I just added the sleep you mentioned right before the click. Still is returning the same problem.

Comment: If I change the click to something like browser.driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element.all(by.css('[ng-value="account.id"]')).get(0).getWebElement()) it allows the tests to pass, but the button does not actually get pressed on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the snippet to be:

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-repeat="account in accounts"]')).then(function (elm) {
    elm[0].click();
});
```

And it seems to be working fine now.